# Angular 4.X: Initialize child components router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have the following app route configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {loadChildren: './modules/faq/faq.module', path: 'faq'},
    {loadChildren: './modules/pagination/pagination.module', path: 'page'},
    {loadChildren: './modules/appointmentAgreement/appointmentAgreement.module#AppointmentAgreementModule', path: 'terminvereinbarung'}
];
```

And the appointmentAgreement child modules route configuration

```
const appointmentAgreementRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    children: [
        {path: 'thema', component: TopicSectionComponent},
        {path: 'filiale', component: BranchSectionComponent},
        {path: 'termin', component: DatetimeSectionComponent},
        {path: 'daten', component: PersonalDataSectionComponent},
        {path: 'bestaetigung', component: ConfirmationSectionComponent},
    ]
}];
```

Now i want the application to redirect to /terminvereinbarung/thema if page /terminvereinbarung is openend.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks a lot in adcance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep all routing as it is just try adding this redirect in children in sub module

```
const appointmentAgreementRoutes: Routes = [{
path: '',
children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'thema', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path: 'thema', component: TopicSectionComponent},
    {path: 'filiale', component: BranchSectionComponent},
    {path: 'termin', component: DatetimeSectionComponent},
    {path: 'daten', component: PersonalDataSectionComponent},
    {path: 'bestaetigung', component: ConfirmationSectionComponent},
 ]
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following in appointmentAgreement component:

```
const appointmentAgreementRoutes: Routes = [{
{
  path: 'terminvereinbarung',
  redirectTo: 'thema',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
  path: 'terminvereinbarung',
  component: TopicSectionComponent,
}
children: [
    {path: 'thema', component: TopicSectionComponent},
    {path: 'filiale', component: BranchSectionComponent},
    {path: 'termin', component: DatetimeSectionComponent},
    {path: 'daten', component: PersonalDataSectionComponent},
    {path: 'bestaetigung', component: ConfirmationSectionComponent},
]
```

}];

Comment: thanks a lot for this fast answer. it looks like you have a syntax issue in your snippet. Can you give the correct one?

Comment: I have updated my answer and removed curly bracket around path

Comment: I tried your updated solution, but unfortunately it doenst work.

calling /terminvereinbarung renders no component

calling /terminvereinbarung/thema gives an error:

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'terminvereinbarung/thema

Comment: Also not working, i cannot select any other child view then, always the TopicSectionComponent gets loaded.

Comment: I have made changes to my answer please check.

Comment: try now again some changes made